# What is the difference between single, double, and triple quotes in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, quotations

In other words, how do I know which one to use?

I know when I use strings. I would do

```
    string = "This is a string"
```

When would I use ' ' or """ """?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`'...'` and `"..."` are equivalent. If you have an apostrophe in the string, it is easier to use `"..."` so you don't have to escape the apostrophe. If you have quotes in the string, it's easier to use `'...'` so you don't have to escape the quotes.

Triple quotes (both varieties, `"""` and `'''` are permitted) allow the string to contain line breaks. These are commonly used for docstrings (and other multi-line comments, including "commenting out" code) and for embedded snippets of other computer languages such as HTML and SQL.

https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

Comment: triple quotes ability to be multi-line strings makes them useful for emulating multi-line comments as well.

Comment: Added some stuff about the uses of triple-quoted strings